# 301 for many domains

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, multiple-domains

We have a main website for a big company, let's say `www.tartempion.com`.

We bought about 60 domain names (let's say `www.tartempion.org`, `www.tartempion.se` but also `www.strangename.net`), mainly to avoid that domain squatters do it.

Is it a good idea to have 301 redirects for all those domains, or would it be better to have no content at all? Can I find some authoritative documentation on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bought all these domains to avoid cyber squatting, you can apply 301 redirects to the main website. It will indicate to visitors all domains belong to your company.

Comment: Thanks. Any reference document to help convince my coworkers that this won't ruin our rankings?

Comment: I don't have a reference document but you can read [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/9740/20122). For me, it's just logical. Big companies like Microsoft... do it.

Comment: Logical to me to, but not to everyone. Microsoft example is a good one to me, but what about unrelated domain names?

Comment: I agree that it is common practice.  I've worked as an employee of several top websites that have hundreds of typo and alternate domain names that redirect to the main site.

Comment: If unrelated domain names have been bought for avoiding cyber squatting only, there is no problem and it's logical, whatever the name of these domains.

Comment: I believe so, but this is no proof. Any example of many domains of a big company redirecting to a single one?

Comment: It's a little bit different but Google purchases many companies and for some of them, it redirects old domain name to `google.com`. Example for [phonetics-arts.com](http://phonetic-arts.com/). You can find some examples of companies which have a domain name redirected to Google on this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mergers_and_acquisitions_by_Google).